# How to return a count of duplicates and unique values into a column in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I currently have this table:

| First_Name | Last_Name |
| --- | --- |
| Jane | Doe |
| John | Smith |
| Bob | Smith |
| Alice | Smith |

And I'm looking to get the table to look for duplicates in the last name and return a value into a new column and exclude any null/unique values like the table below, or return a Yes/No into the third column.

| First_Name | Last_Name | Duplicates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | Doe | 0 |
| John | Smith | 3 |
| Bob | Smith | 3 |
| Alice | Smith | 3 |

OR

| First_Name | Last_Name | Duplicates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | Doe | No |
| John | Smith | Yes |
| Bob | Smith | Yes |
| Alice | Smith | Yes |

When I'm trying to enter the query into the Access Database, I keep getting the run-time 3141 error.

The code that I tried in order to get the first option is:
SELECT first_name, last_name, COUNT (last_name) AS Duplicates
FROM table
GROUP BY last_name, first_name
HAVING COUNT(last_name)=>0

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery.  But I would recommend `1` instead of `0`:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t as t2
        where t2.last_name = t.last_name
       )
from t;
```

If you *really* want zero instead of 1, then one method is:

```
select t.*,
       (select iif(count(*) = 1, 0, count(*))
        from t as t2
        where t2.last_name = t.last_name
       )
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I want to ensure all previous records remain visible, so the only thing that changes are the values in the duplicate column and this would include zeros. In your second query, what does the "iif" stand for?

Comment: @Smaands123 . . . Neither of these filters any rows.